# JavaScript: Set Interval runs only once?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am trying to make the show button bring back the h1 tag but it stops after reaching opacity: 0.1 instead of continuing all the way to opacity: 1.

I have tried debugging on Firebug for hours but cannot seem to crack it. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Flesh and Bone</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Flesh and Bone</h1>
<button id="fade">Fade</button>
<button id="show">Bring Back</button>
<h2>The Killers</h2>
<script>
    var el = document.querySelector("h1");
    var fade = document.getElementById("fade");
    var show = document.getElementById("show");
    var fader = function () {
        el.style.opacity = 1;
        var timer = setInterval(function (){
            el.style.opacity -= 0.1;
            if (el.style.opacity == 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 40);
    }
    var shower = function () {
        el.style.opacity = 0;
        var timer = setInterval(function (){
            el.style.opacity += 0.1;
            if (el.style.opacity == 1) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 40);
    }
    fade.onclick = fader;
    show.onclick = shower;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just use `.animate` or `fadeTo`?

Comment: @BradChristie There is no jQuery in this question.

Comment: @Jivings: I'm aware, just being a little funny with all the jQuery questions on the boards. I guess it's hard to gauge over the interwebs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the behaviour of floating point arithmetic. Which is explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/334274). The opacity is never actually reaching 0, so the timer is never cleared.

The solution is to use `toFixed(1)` when you are performing your subtraction and addition:

```
var timer = setInterval(function (){
        el.style.opacity = (el.style.opacity - 0.1).toFixed(1);
        if (el.style.opacity == 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 40);
```

JSfiddle example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/28XNK/2/

Answer (score 2):

A few things are contributing to this:

1. `el.style.opacity` is always a `String`, so `+=` will concatenate rather than add. Keep the opacity in a separate variable so it remains a `Number`.
2. Numbers [aren't so precise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004) as to `== 1` or `== 0` exactly at the end. Use `>= 1` and `<= 0` instead.

---

```
var fader = function () {
    var opacity = 1;
    el.style.opacity = opacity;
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        opacity -= 0.1;
        el.style.opacity = Math.max(opacity, 0);
        if (opacity <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 40);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qBgJY/

Answer (score 1):

opacity is a string property so you need to convert it to float to modify it:

```
el.style.opacity = parseFloat(el.style.opacity) + 0.1;
```